# How do I fix data is splitting between two groups with the same project number?

Tags: reporting-services

I've created a simple report to show customer invoices based on project number. I grouped it by project number. When I run the report, I see two groups for the same project number. I'm fairly new to Reporting Services, so I'm not sure what to do to fix it!

Report sample:

[image: Report Sample]

Report Layout:
[Report Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG3IS.png)

Query Data:
[Sample Query Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UstyZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your rowgroup properties have grouping just on Project Number.

Also check that the project numbers are in fact the same, it might be you have instances where there are leading or trailing spaces.

To check this do a quick query on the table such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectNumber FROM myTable WHERE ProjectNumber LIKE ('%999-10%')
```

If this comes back with more than one result then **either**

1. Change your dataset set query trim the column with something like

   SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ProjectNumber)) as ProjectNumber, myOtherFields FROM myTable
2. Change your textbox that displays the project number and the row group properties to  `=TRIM(Fields!ProjectNumber.Value)` (case sensitive column name)

---

More trouble shooting advice

Everything looks OK, it might be worth even creating a new report from scratch with the minimum steps to reproduce and see if the issue shows up again.

As an additional step, which 'may' give you a clue about what is happening you could append a row number to your dataset query, include that in your report output and then look for a pattern. There are lots of apparently duplicate rows shows in the report so it's difficult to know which is which.

try changing your dataset query to something like

```
SELECT Phase, JCCo, Job, CostType, ActualDate, Source, Description, ActualHours, ActualUnits, ActualCost,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Phase, JCCo, Job, CostType, ActualDate, Source, Description, ActualHours, ActualUnits, ActualCost) as RowNum
FROM bjCCD
```

Then add the new RowNum field to your report, look for patterns in each group of rows. I'm still convinced that either there is additional grouping or the job field has hidden characters as the report design is very simple there is very little else to go wrong.

Comment: I confirmed the row group properties only have 1 grouping and it's set for project number. I also ran the suggested query and only got one result. Any other thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Assuming the screenshot you posted was the preview, check that your interactive page size (in report properties) is not set too small. Try making it larger to see if there is any change. If this does not help, please edit your question and show you complete report design and some sample data as it appears in the results of your dataset query.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Alan. I've tested the interactive page size and that doesn't make an impact. I've added 2 more screen shots to my question. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: I've added a few more things to try. From what you have said, everything shoudl be OK, so it might be worth sharing the rdl file if nothing else helps

Comment: Also, did you try to change the grouping expression to trim out any lead/trailing spaces in the Job field as I suggested in the original answer?

Comment: Alan - I appreciate all your help. We took a look at the spaces in the database and ultimately figured out that was causing the issue. We added TRIM to the field and now things are grouping as expected.

Comment: OK great news! If my answer actually answered the question, could you please mark is as accepted. This helps future SO users find answers to similar questions.